# How to change value 0 to not valid and 1 to valid in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for bad english,
I've some cell with 0 value and 1 value in my microsoft excel, and i want to show 0 values with not valid and 1 values with valid without affecting the formula.

My current excel :

```
x A B C D E F 
1 1 0 0 0 1 0
2 0 1 1 0 0 1
3 1 0 1 0 0 1
4 0 1 1 1 1 1
5 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

What i want :

```
valid notvalid notvalid notvalid valid notvalid
0 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: =if(mycell,"valid","not valid")

Comment: @WNG i want to change the value in the same exact cell, if A1 is 0 so A1 will be invalid. is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom number format (ctrl+1) of `[Color13][=1]v\ali\d;[Color9][=0]\notv\ali\d;;` on the cells.

[image]

In addition to the valid/notvalid display text, I've added dark blue font for the valids and dark red for notvalid.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are now working in `Worksheet1`, if you don't want to edit the formula you currently have in cells `A1:F5`, you can:

- either go to/create `Worksheet2` and select the cell `A1` **OR** select the cell `A7` in `Worksheet1`.
- write in `Worksheet1!A7` or `Worksheet2!A1` the following formula:

`=IF(Worksheet1!A1=1,"valid","notvalid")`

- copy the formula dragging the fill handle as needed.

I hope I understood well what you would like to do.